# Joining two kafka engine tables in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to join two tables as following

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW db.data_v ON CLUSTER  shard1 TO db.table 
AS 
SELECT JSON_VALUE(db.table2_queue.message, '$.after.id') bid, 
JSON_VALUE(message, '$.after.brand_id') AS brand_id, 
JSON_VALUE(message, '$.after.id') AS id 
FROM
db.table1_queue lq 
Join db.table2_queue bq 
on JSON_VALUE(bq.message, '$.after.id') =  JSON_VALUE(lq.message, '$.after.brand_id')
```

However i got an empty result:

```
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec.
```

Comment: it does not work like this. Kafka tables are not real tables, they are consumers. If you query data from the Kafka table (table2_queue) it moves offset, and the next read will see no commited rows.

Comment: Probably this is impossible to implement in Clickhouse in a good way. The best you can do is to join before, in some ETL. Or you can consume data into two separate tables and join them later.

Comment: the best way to handle this is to create a materialised view and join the two views together. it worked perfectly